# How to send file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, upload, telegram

I want to send an image to my telegram bot via javascript (not Node.js). For this I need the token of the bot and my Telegram user ID.

Sending text messages works fine, I also succeeded in sending photos, which I gave as LINK. Now I want to take my own photos and send them directly to my bot.

*This is a part of the telegram documentation:*

[image]

So as I understood it, I can also send images as a file and not as a link using a post request. Unfortunately I had no great success with the implementation:

```js
let token = "xy",
  chat_id = "123"
let url = `https://api.telegram.org/bot${token}/sendPhoto?chat_id=${chat_id}`;

$("form").submit(function(e) {
  let formData = new FormData(this);
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    success: function(r) {
      console.log(r);
    },
    error: (e) => {
      console.log("Error", e)
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input id="fileInput" type="file" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

How can I implement this in pure javascript and working?

Note that `https://api.telegram.org/bot${token}/sendPhoto?chat_id=${chat_id}&photo=${link_to_photo}` is working.

Comment: Need to set `processData:false` when sending FormData and set multi part content type header Also need to make sure API is CORS enabled for such posts

Answer (score 0):

Though it's not obvious from the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), you need to set two more `ajax` options:

```
processData: false
```

> **processData** (default: true)
>   *Type: Boolean*   By default, data passed in to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed
>   and transformed into a query string, fitting to the default
>   content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If you want to send
>   a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this option to false.

**FormData should be sent unprocessed**

```
contentType: false
```

> **contentType** (default: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8')
>   *Type: Boolean or String*   When sending data to the server, use this content type. Default is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;
>   charset=UTF-8", which is fine for most cases. If you explicitly pass
>   in a content-type to $.ajax(), then it is always sent to the server
>   (even if no data is sent). As of jQuery 1.6 you can pass false to tell
>   jQuery to not set any content type header. Note: The W3C
>   XMLHttpRequest specification dictates that the charset is always
>   UTF-8; specifying another charset will not force the browser to change
>   the encoding. Note: For cross-domain requests, setting the content
>   type to anything other than application/x-www-form-urlencoded,
>   multipart/form-data, or text/plain will trigger the browser to send a
>   preflight OPTIONS request to the server.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: 'POST',
  data: formData,
  
  processData: false, // TO SEND DATA UNPROCESSED
  contentType: false, // TO OVERRIDE THE DEFAULT 
  
  success: function(r) {console.log(r);},
  error: (e) => {console.log("Error", e)}
//  return false;  <-- REMOVE THIS FROM HERE
});
```

Comment: This is not working for me. I got an error exactely as I did.

Comment: @jonas00, your question does not mention any errors. What error do you get?